# MYSQL update database

Tags: php, mysql

There is a column which is number_of_date in additional_leave table & when it is update, the column of employee table which is additional_leave should be updated accordingly. Its work. When apply those additional leave by clicking button as following image the employee table's additional_leave column value should be minus.

[image: the issue]

---

It also works. But the problem is when I'm again come to the additional leave display page after applying those additional leave, DB will again update as before value which is number of date in additional_leave table. The DB value does not remain as minus value. Following is my code.

```
function additional_leave_apply($userID){
if(isset($_POST['apply2'])){
    $category=$_POST['category1'];
    $number_of_date=$_POST['no_of_date1'];

    $resul=mysql_query("SELECT * from employee where emp_id='$userID'") or die("query error".mysql_error());
    $result3 = mysql_fetch_array($resul);

    $annual_additional=$result3['annual_additional'];
    $casual_additional=$result3['casual_additional'];
    $medical_additional=$result3['medical_additional'];

    $value1=$annual_additional-$number_of_date;
    $value2=$casual_additional-$number_of_date;
    $value3=$medical_additional-$number_of_date;

    if($category=='Annual'){
        $result= "UPDATE employee SET annual_additional='$value1' WHERE emp_id='$userID'";
        $query=mysql_query($result);
    }
    elseif($category=='Casual'){
        $result= "UPDATE employee SET casual_additional='$value2' WHERE emp_id='$userID'";
        $query=mysql_query($result);
    }
    else{
        $result= "UPDATE employee SET medical_additional='$value3' WHERE emp_id='$userID'";
        $query=mysql_query($result);
    }

    // header('Location: index.php');
    echo("success");
}
else{
    {}
}
```

This is function to display additional leave.

```
function additional_lave_annual($userID){

$resul=mysql_query("SELECT * from employee where emp_id='$userID'") or die("query error".mysql_error());
$result3 = mysql_fetch_array($resul);
$emp_division=$result3['division'];
$emp_date=$result3['employment_date'];

$resu=mysql_query("SELECT * from additional_leave where leave_type='Annual' AND (division='$emp_division' OR division='all_dpt') ORDER BY additional_id DESC limit 1") or die("query error".mysql_error());
$result3 = mysql_fetch_array($resu);
$added_date=$result3['added_date'];

if($added_date>=$emp_date){

    $number_of_datee= "SELECT SUM(number_of_date) AS number_of_date FROM additional_leave WHERE  division IN ('$emp_division','all_dpt') AND leave_type='Annual' AND added_date>='$emp_date'";
    $res_qry22     = mysql_query($number_of_datee) or die ('Invalid query :: <br/>'.$number_of_datee.' <br/>'.mysql_error());

    $rowqr = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_qry22);
    $number_date33 = $rowqr ['number_of_date'];

    $result= "UPDATE employee SET annual_additional='$number_date33' WHERE emp_id='$userID'";
    $query=mysql_query($result);

    $resul=mysql_query("SELECT * from employee where emp_id='$userID'") or die("query error".mysql_error());
    $result3 = mysql_fetch_array($resul);
    $annual_additional=$result3['annual_additional'];

    $result= "UPDATE employee SET annual_additional='$number_date33' WHERE emp_id='$userID'";
    $query=mysql_query($result);


if (additional_leave_apply($userID)){

    echo ($annual_additional);?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <?php echo  " <a href='apply_additional_leave.php'><button type='button' class='btn btn-info btn-xs'>Apply this leave</button></a>";

}
else{
    echo ($annual_additional);?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <?php echo  " <a href='apply_additional_leave.php'><button type='button' class='btn btn-info btn-xs'>Apply this leave</button></a>";
}
```

---

How can I fix this problem. Please help !

Comment: Some sugestions: 1) You should return true or false in additional_leave_apply function. 2) Use JOIN 3) Use mysqli or PDO

Comment: A function should return something so add `return` at the end of both functions. Also what if you change from `isset` to `!empty` at the top of first function?

Comment: A suggestion. use mysqli functions instead mysql. because mysql is deprecated.